# Converting auth into promise in Angular 2 firebase

Tags: firebase, promise, firebase-authentication, angularfire, observable

I'm using the auth parameter in Firebase in Angular2 for obtaining information about the currently logged in user. I want to use this information to decide the path for where to store information. I don't want to subscribe to the auth observable as this will call my database function multiple times. Therefore I tried converting to a promise

I'm looking to do something like this:

**Service**

```
public getUserInformation(): Observable<Person> {
    return this.af.auth.map(authInfo => {
      return new Person(
        authInfo.auth.uid,
        authInfo.auth.displayName,
        authInfo.auth.displayName,
        authInfo.auth.photoURL
      )
    }).toPromise()
      .then(res => { 
         console.log(res)
         // Here I want to insert a row in my DB using the authInfo 
      }

  }
```

If I subscribe directly I get the Auth details as expected but this will call my database call many times

```
  public getUserInformation(): Observable<Person> {
    return this.af.auth
      .subscribe(res => { 
         console.log(res )  
         // Call to my DB           
      })
  }
```

Any clues why the promise never resolves? I have included toPromise in my import

Comment: I'm not working with Firebase, but I guess that's because `auth` observable isn't completed. I see no reason why it should be converted to promise here, you can do the same thing with observables. But for one-time subscription it may be ` this.af.auth.take(1).map(...)....`.

Comment: You're right, this does it! Thanks